# Find the domain and range of $f\left(x\right)=\sec^{-1}\left(2x-x^{2}\right)$.

Tags: trigonometry

As the title suggests, find the domain and range of $$f\left(x\right)=\sec^{-1}\left(2x-x^{2}\right)$$
I did find the domain to be either $x=1$ or $x\in\left(-\infty,1-\sqrt{2}\right]\cup\left[1+\sqrt{2},\infty\right)$. But finding the $\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\right)$ function is turning out to be really confusing. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For domain just solve:
$f(x)\leq -1$  or  $f(x)\geq1$

For range:
$f(x)=0$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}<f(x)\leq \pi$

Answer (score 1):

For the domain of $f(x)$; $2x-x^{2}\geq1$ . And also $2x-x^{2}\leq-1$ . So, you will get $x^{2}-2x+1\leq0$ and $x^{2}-2x-1\geq0$ . Now you will get 3 values of $x$ $i.e.$ $1-\sqrt{2},1,1+\sqrt{2}$ . Now $x^{2}-2x+1$ is never$<0$. It can be equal to $0$. So, the only possibility is $x^{2}-2x-1\geq0$ . So, your domain will be $(-\infty,1-\sqrt{2}]\cup[1+\sqrt{2},\infty)$ . And Range will be $(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$.